# How to map data from XML to JavaScript objects which requires logic in parsing?

Tags: javascript, xml, mapping, javascript-objects, es6-class

Given the following **xml data structure**:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <name>foobar</name>
        <price currency="USD">280.0</price>
        <url>https://domain/path/id=#id1&baz=baz1
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <name>foobar2</name>
        <price currency="USD">160.0</price>
        <url>https://domain/path/id=#id2&baz=baz1
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <name>foobar</name>
        <price currency="USD">120.0</price>
        <url>https://domain/path/id=#id1&baz=baz3
    </foo>
</root>
```

I must extract a data subset that is mapped to a JavaScript object. This requires parsing urls'query strings and extract `id` and `baz` values.

`id` is what identifies the `foo` data block as being unique. It sounds weird to put a unique identifier in a url that must be parsed but that's the response from a business partner and I have on control on this data structure layout.

I am hesitating between two aprroches:

**Approach 1**

1. Extract subset of data from xml response (filtering and parsing processing)
2. Initialize instance of es6 class that will only holds the required data

In this scenario what would be the pros and cons of using a class instance vs an object literal as it will mainly acts as a data container with no associated logic ?

**Approach 2**

1. Pass all the data in a es6 Class constructor which calls a method which would do the data filtering and parsing ?

I am using `xmldoc` npm pakcage to convert the XML string to a JavaScript Object allowing me to easily access to data.

Comment: "*Does it makes sense to use classes rather than object literals*" - The question should be "what's the difference between those two?" JS classes aren't real classes, they are just syntactic sugar over the prototype-based structures.

Comment: Yeah absolutely correct let me edit my question